# question search based on posted time

Tags: discussion, feature-request, usability

Is there a way to search questions posted between certain date & time.

I know I can add it to favorites if I would like to follow the question, but sometimes when I see duplicate question posted by user (or someother ID) let us say after an hour (or) so, it take lot of time to click next, next and find out the exact question. Sometimes keywords also may list lot of similar questions.

I think search based on date and time may help.

Thank you,

Comment: I've also been looking for a function like this, e.g. time:last-month or time:20130101-20130301. Would definitely be useful.